# Why has my phone started charging slowly from my laptop's USB port?

Tags: usb-power-delivery

I understand that not all USB ports are created with power delivery in mind, and therefore some charge devices slower than others. What confuses me is the change in behavior. I swear around two years ago I could charge my phone at a reasonable speed from my laptop (around 3 hours maybe?). However, recently, it takes over five hours if I'm not using my phone at all simultaniously. Could there be some sort of USB driver that was updated and broke quicker charging?

Laptop: MSI GS63
Phone: Galaxy S8

Comment: It's not the USB that's changed, it's the phone battery is now 5 years old.

Comment: It may also be the phone or software running on it. Many phones (I know I had an S6 that did this) limit their charging speed if the phone is "awake" and doing things and you only get full speed charging if the phone has properly gone to sleep. The screen being off doesn't mean that a progr is not running in the background keeping the OS awake and there are some Android programs to diagnose sleep states and "wakelock" problems.

Comment: Also if programs on your phone are actively running and using CPU they will obviously be using more power and charging slower as a result, but if there are problems on your phone then [Android.se] would be a better place as phones are generally off topic here except insofar as the problem is in connecting to a computer

Comment: My first thought would also go towards the phone battery, but additionally, did you use the same port as you used to? There was a transitional period where some laptops came with a mixture of USB 2, 3.0/3.1 ports. There is a significant difference in power output between these.

Comment: There's also OS upgrades. Newer versions are almost always a good idea to upgrade to, but they may have a larger resource footprint on your phone. Note that I do *not* recommend downgrading, just that this might be one more additional factor in why your phone draws more power and therefore charges slower.

Comment: I would try a new cable first.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons why your phone is charging slow. For example:

1. USB Port: doesn't provide enough power. Try a real power supply (a higher Watt [W] or Ampere [A] order often also Milliampere [0,001A] number usually means faster charging capabilities)
   If you are using a PC/laptop, you might have disabled the fast charging option in your laptop
2. Cables: the cable can also limit the charging speed. This happens, especially if they are old or broken.
3. Temperature: if your phone is too warm or too cold, it might reduce the charging speed to reduce damage on your battery.
4. Almost fully charged Batteries are usually also charged with a reduced speed to avoid damage.